# Avoid overflow of the page caused by a large div

Tags: html, css

this is my jsfiddle main structure: http://jsfiddle.net/LQtaJ/
There are 2 divs inside a div

```
<div id="c1">
    <div id="c2"></div>
    <div id="c3"></div>
</div>
```

and I would like that, even if `#c2` and `#c3` overflow the window, no x scrollbar have to appear.
So, i know that I can use `overflow-x: hidden` to the `<body>`, but are there other ways that do not globally affect everything? Like putting some negative margin?

Thanks

Comment: try forcing #c1 to have "overflow: hidden". If you want to let it overflow, but don't want to let the WINDOW overflow, you should wrap everything inside another div with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQtaJ/1/ (your fiddle, updated).

I added "main" div and it's style:

```
#main {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

In this fiddle, I wrap your layout inside a bigger static div. THAT div has overflow:hidden.  This means: even when c2 and c3 overflow c1, the full content will not overflow the window (i.e. in this case, the wrapping #main div).

If you want to not let them overflow c1, put overflow:hidden in c1 instead of in main.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear your question, but if I understood right instead to apply `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` you can do directly on the wrapper `#c1`

Answer (score 1):

A little silly, but you can just add a wrap around your c1 wrap: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQtaJ/2/)

html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="c1">
        <div id="c2"></div>
        <div id="c3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#c1 {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999;
    height: 300px;
}
#c2, #c3 {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
}
#c2 {
    left: -1000px;
}
#c3 {
    right: -1000px;
}
```

Comment: Might also need a max-width:100% for #wrap

Comment: See fiddle - no need.